# How to make canvas elements reach the center of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm populating the canvas with arcs at random position but now I want them to move to the center of the canvas, but they just jump to the center of the canvas and not slowly moving to the center.
The road so far

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script>
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var c = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
    myCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    myCanvas.width = 600;
    myCanvas.height = 600;
    var myArr = [];
    var firstCircle;

    function Circledraw(x, y, r) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;

        this.draw = function() {
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            c.fillStyle = "#fff";
            c.fill();
        }

        this.update = function() {
            this.x = myCanvas.clientWidth/2;
            this.y = myCanvas.clientHeight/2;
        }

    }

    for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){
        var x = Math.random() * myCanvas.clientWidth;
        var y = Math.random() * myCanvas.clientHeight;
        var r = 20;
        firstCircle = new Circledraw(x, y, 20);
        firstCircle.draw();
        myArr.push(firstCircle);
    }

    setInterval(circleFall, 1000);

    function circleFall() {
        c.clearRect(0,0, myCanvas.clientWidth, myCanvas.clientHeight);
        for(var z =0; z < myArr.length; z++){
            myArr[z].update();
            firstCircle.draw();
        }

    }


</script>
```

How do i fix this??

EDIT:

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = "#e74c3c";

function Vectors(x, y, r) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;

  var centerX = canvas.width/2;
  var centerY = canvas.height/2;

  var diffX = centerX - this.x;
  var diffY = centerY - this.y;
  var angle = Math.atan(diffY, diffX);
  var speed = 1;

  var vector = {
    x: Math.cos(angle) * speed,
    y: Math.sin(angle) * speed
  }

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.fillStyle = '#fff';
    c.fill();
  }

  this.update = function() {  
        this.x += vector.x;
        this.y += vector.y;
  }

}

var newCircle = new Vectors(90, 100, 10);


function animate() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  newCircle.update();
  newCircle.draw();
}
animate();
```

The first arc is placed with co-ordinates rather than random position but it's not moving towards the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `myCanvas.clientWidth/2` and `myCanvas.clientHeight/2` will always return the same result, in this case the center point of the canvas.

A better approach is to use a vector based on the angle between the original point and center - something like:

```
var diffX = myCanvas.width / 2 - this.x,
    diffY = myCanvas.height / 2 - this.y,
    angle = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX),
    speed = 1;

var vector = {
  x: Math.cos(angle) * speed,
  y: Math.sin(angle) * speed
};
```

Then in the update method add the vector to the position:

```
this.update = function() {
  // todo add some checks here to see if it's close enough to center
  this.x += vector.x;
  this.y += vector.y;
}
```

Combine this with `requestAnimationFrame()` instead of using `setInterval()` will make the animation silk smooth as well.

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
myCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
myCanvas.width = 600;
myCanvas.height = 600;
var myArr = [];
var firstCircle;

function Circledraw(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    
    var cx = myCanvas.width/2, 
        cy = myCanvas.height/2,
        diffX = cx - this.x,
        diffY = cy - this.y,
        angle = Math.atan2(diffY, diffX),
        speed = 1;

    var tolerance = 2; 
    var vector = {
      x: Math.cos(angle) * speed,
      y: Math.sin(angle) * speed
    };


    this.update = function() {
      if (!(this.x > cx - tolerance && this.x < cx + tolerance &&
          this.y > cy - tolerance && this.y < cy + tolerance)) {
        this.x += vector.x;
        this.y += vector.y;
      }
      else { /* this can be used to detect finished action */ }
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        c.fillStyle = "#fff";
        c.fill();
    }

}

for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){
    var x = Math.random() * myCanvas.width;
    var y = Math.random() * myCanvas.height;
    var r = 20;
    firstCircle = new Circledraw(x, y, 20);
    firstCircle.draw();
    myArr.push(firstCircle);
}

(function circleFall() {
    c.clearRect(0,0, myCanvas.clientWidth, myCanvas.clientHeight);
    for(var z =0; z < myArr.length; z++){
        myArr[z].update();
        myArr[z].draw();  // make sure to draw th current circle
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(circleFall);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

A different approach is to use linear interpolation which allows the dots to finish in center at the same time:

```js
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var c = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
myCanvas.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
myCanvas.width = 600;
myCanvas.height = 600;
var myArr = [];
var firstCircle;

function Circledraw(x, y, r, step) {
    var startX, startY;
    var cx = myCanvas.width / 2;
    var cy = myCanvas.height / 2;

    this.x = startX = x;
    this.y = startY = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.t = 0;
    this.step = step; // since we work with normalized values, this tend to be small

    function lerp(v1, v2, t) {     // linear interpolation
      return v1 + (v2 - v1) * t;   // t = [0.0, 1.0] 0 = v1, 1 = v2
    }
    
    this.update = function() {
      if (this.t <= 1) {
        this.x = lerp(startX, cx, this.t);  // set abs. position based on t
        this.y = lerp(startY, cy, this.t);
        this.t += this.step;                // increase step for t
      }
      else { 
        /* this can be used to detect finished action, for example resetting pos */ 
        this.x = startX = Math.random() * myCanvas.width;
        this.y = startY = Math.random() * myCanvas.height;
        this.t = 0;
      }
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        c.fillStyle = "#fff";
        c.fill();
    }

}

for(var i =0; i < 10; i++){
    var x = Math.random() * myCanvas.width;
    var y = Math.random() * myCanvas.height;
    var r = 20;
    firstCircle = new Circledraw(x, y, 20, Math.random() * 0.04 + 0.005);
    firstCircle.draw();
    myArr.push(firstCircle);
}

(function circleFall() {
    c.clearRect(0,0, myCanvas.clientWidth, myCanvas.clientHeight);
    for(var z =0; z < myArr.length; z++){
        myArr[z].update();
        myArr[z].draw();  // make sure to draw th current circle
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(circleFall);
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked like a charm..I wasn't even thinking of this approach. Cheers!!, but the angle thing, like where you used cos,sin how did you get to that I'm trying to figure out the approach to it.

Comment: No problem. It's just trigonometry used to find the angle between the current point and center using the difference between them as an initial vector for atan2. Sin and cos is then used to find the step values relative to the angle represented as the vector. And speed then basically becomes "radius" for cos/sin, or here: step per frame so the point travel along that invisible line.

Comment: thanks, i tried your code but as of now the arcs are moving randomly in the canvas, but not getting pulled to the center, even after checking when they hit the center of the canvas but since the random path they barely touch the center

Comment: @tankit88 since they have floating point values for positions you have to add a margin/tolerance to the check (depending on speed as well). Let me add an example. You can also use linear interpolation by the way instead of vector.

Comment: @tankit88 added one example using linear interpolation as well.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and effort, this is what I wanted. Thanks again :)

Comment: I am trying to exactly like your code again, but this time for a single element but somehow it's not progressing to the center but it's just falling down. I have edited my original code with yours, what's wrong here?

Comment: The `Math.atan` should be `Math.atan2` (notice the 2 at the end).